# Image path failed to store into Object class

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, mutablelist

In fragment A, I trying to get image object from server and store them into `totalListImage`. This steps works fine.

```
 var totalListImage: MutableList<Image> = mutableListOf()
 fun getWorkRequestImage() {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val request = WebApi.getImages(activity, obj?.id!!)
            request?.images?.let {
                for (i in it!!.iterator()) {
                    totalListImage?.add(i)
                }
            }
            mImageListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
```

In same fragment, I allow user to take image and store the captured image into `totalListImage`.

Here  onActivityResult

```
 var path = data?.getExtras()?.getString("bitmap")
    if (path != null) {
            Log.d(TAG,path)
            val images = Image()
            images.image?.url = path
            totalListImage.add(images)
            display()
       }
```

Finally in display method, I want to display all the url. But I get null pointer on the last captured image.

```
fun display() {
        for (i in totalListImage) {
            Log.d(TAG, i.image?.url)
        }
    }
```

If I remove the captured image, I get this

```
D/AFragment: https://xxx/image/633/1562424667277.png
D/AFragment: https://xxx/image/637/1562426838223.png
```

The path of the captured image confirm not null, as I display it I saw this

```
D/AFragment: /data/user/0/xxxk/cache/images/1562437144046.png
```

Why I can't save the last image's path into `images.image?.url` ?

**Images**

```
class Images : Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey
    var id = ""
    @Ignore
    var image : Image?=null
}
```

**Image**

```
@Parcelize
class Image(

    @ColumnInfo(name = "image")
    var url: String ? =null
) : Serializable,Parcelable
```

Comment: How does the `Image` class look like? Maybe `images.image` is null. Please post also the logcat of the error

Comment: 1.If are using external storage , Can you add the Manifest Permissions as well John ?
2.val images = Image() i believe it's now constant if the image url is also constant then you won't be able to alter it , try to make it var and if you can of course logcat this image url before and after `images.image?.url = path`

Comment: @gpunto images.image is null. How can I fix ?

Comment: @HossamEldeenOnsy images.image is null.

Comment: You will need to initialize it before putting the urlpath into it as follows 
`val images = Images()

Like This --> images.image = Image()  <-- Like This 

images.image?.url = path
totalListImage.add(images)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to this code:

```
val images = Image()
images.image?.url = path
totalListImage.add(images)
```

and assuming that you meant `val images = Images()` (otherwise this snippet won't even compile),
then the issue is that `images.image` is `null`.
That's because of the definition of the `Images` class, where you have `var image : Image?=null`.

To solve you either:

- change the class definition to have a not-null default value, like:

```
var image : Image? = Image()
```

- or manually initialize it in the snippet above, like:

```
val images = Images()
images.image = Image()
images.image?.url = path
totalListImage.add(images)
```